# How to calculate the Manhattan Distance with SQL function / procedure

Tags: sql, distance

Does anybody have a simple function / store procedure on how to calculate the Manhattan Distance when given two XY coordinate pairs?

Answer (score 2):

It's just the sum of the difference between coordinate pairs:

```
|x2 - x1| + |y2 - y1|
```

This hardly warrants a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MANHATTAN_DISTANCE(X1 NUMBER,
                                              Y1 NUMBER,
                                              X2 NUMBER,
                                              Y2 NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ABS(X1 - X2) + ABS(Y1 - Y2);
END MANHATTAN_DISTANCE;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy. The Manhattan Distance is just the sum of the distances in each dimension, so:

```
SELECT ABS(x2 - x1) + ABS(y2 - y1) AS manhattan_distance FROM your_table
```